# Can I mount a router to the Ridgid R4510 table saw?

Tags: powertools, routers, table-saw

I'd like to purchase a Ridgid R4510 table saw, but I want to make sure I can mount a router under it. Should I be concerned with whether this specific table saw is going to allow it or do pretty much all table saws accommodate a router attachment? Also, would there be a commercially available router attachment for this table. I noticed that most people create their own attachments, but I might like to save some time and just buy one.

Comment: You'd have to either contact Ridgid and ask them if it can accept the attachment you have in mind, or contact the vendor of the attachment and ask them if their product will fit this model of Ridgid saw...

Answer (score -2):

Nothing commercially available nor would I expect one.  I've made one for mine with a fairly detailed build thread on the Router Forums.

http://www.routerforums.com/table-mounted-routing/35529-router-insert-ridgid-r4510-table-saw.html

Comment: Answers that relay on links are only useful if the link does not die. Please consider describing some of the information in the link, so the information can live on even if the link dies.